# Multiple hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I'm writing a paper using Microsoft Word that must have all figures in Appendices. I have found myself in this situation: I use one figure to define multiple concepts, I have created multiples hyperlinks to the figure, and a hyperlink to each of the part of the text beside the title of the figure:

..., See Figure 1.01 A...

..., See Figure 1.01 B...

..., See Figure 1.01 C...

.

.

.

**Figure 1.01 A B C**

I have done this hoping to improve the reading experience, but I want to know if it is possible to do this the other way: creating multiple hyperlinks to one so that when I click this hyperlink, it takes me back to the last place I called it.

Comment: I don't really understand what's being described here. If the endnote has a link that will take you back, it can only have a link to a single location. (It would take you back to only one of the three places.) If multiple locations in the running text have links to the same endnote, the only way to get back to the specific place you came from would be based on the application itself. In a browser, you can use the **Back** button. In Word (for Windows anyway), I believe `<Alt><Left>` does the same thing. But you can't *encode* that into a single link in the endnote.

Comment: @JasonBassford you understand pretty well, I'm looking for a way to accomplish the exposed above to improve my solution, because in some occasions the reader's has not enough knowledge about the application they use and so improve their experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal this way:

1. Create a macro. I named mine "AltLeft".
2. Open the macro editor and add the SendKeys command, like this:

`Sub AltLeft()
    ' AltLeft Macro
    SendKeys ("%{LEFT}")
End Sub`

3. The string "%{LEFT}" tells Word to send the Alt-LeftArrow key sequence. This key sequence will take the user back to the last hyperlink clicked.
4. Assign the AltLeft macro to a button and save it to your document. (Note: you will have to save the document in Word's macro-enabled format (.docm) so that the macro will work.)

Comment: This add the go back to link button to the word document it won't work, because I need to save the paper as  .pdf (I apologize I didn't mentioned before, I have edited the question), that is why I need to do it with hyperlinks or other solution in text that it can be use when I save it as  .pdf

Comment: So what you really need, @DavidDíaz, is a way to edit your final PDF document to add those hyperlinks. This is possible with the full paid version of Acrobat, or one of the subscription models, but I don't think you can do it with the free Acrobat Reader.